# php preg_grep - works pretty fine, but I need to limit the search term

Tags: php, regex

I'm using preg_grep to make database queries per section, per example my database fields have footer_SOMETHING, footer_left, footer_middle and footer_right.

So my question is, having this:

```
preg_grep('/footer_left.*/', $colunas)
```

all my footer_left_**** are included in my queries, but how do I do it to just return footer_ excluding left, middle or right?

example

footer_color

footer_left_border

footer_middle_width

footer_right_height

I just want to have

footer_color

Thanks in advance,

Pluda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want just `footer_color` and similar entries returned, then you can use a [negative assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to exclude `left,right,middle` with:

```
 preg_grep('/footer_(?!left|right|middle).*/', $colunas)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :-

```
preg_grep('/^footer_[^middle|left|right]/', $colunas);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply, but I need the opposite, I want everything that does not have left, middle or right. Thanks

Comment: oh my ...you have to update your question to be more understandable (I do an update to my answer now);